# Could would add an electronjs tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Could we add an electron or maybe installable web apps tag or something?

I would like to add there are NW.js and electron and Brackets-shell but frankly Electron IMO is by far the most popular.

It would help searching because electron apps tend to be cross platform more so then say a C# app.

Wiki stolen formerly from Stack Overflow.

> Electron (formerly Atom Shell) is a framework created by GitHub that lets you write cross-platform desktop applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Electron is based upon Node.js and Chromium.

1. [Has anybody made an Electron app that runs the Windows "cmd.exe" shell/terminal?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47423/has-anybody-made-an-electron-app-that-runs-the-windows-cmd-exe-shell-terminal)
2. [JSON Feed Reader for Windows or Self-Hosted](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48639/json-feed-reader-for-windows-or-self-hosted)
3. [CAD editor library for Javascript](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50195/cad-editor-library-for-javascript)
4. [Can you convert html, css and javascript into a exe?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14797/can-you-convert-html-css-and-javascript-into-a-exe/50666#50666)
5. [PNG viewer that displays alpha channel as transparent](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35474/png-viewer-that-displays-alpha-channel-as-transparent/38906#38906)

Comment: Could you please include in your question: 1) The tag wiki to be used 2) The list of all questions on the site that should be tagged with it (or just five if there are too many). Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I just copied the StackOverflow tag for now.  Linked 5 questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the electron tag.

Out of the 5 questions you linked to, 2 were links to *answers* that use electron. I did not apply the tag to them, since tags are for questions (you would not see a question asking "*Command-line text editor for UNIX*" and tag it "emacs" just because emacs is a possible answer).